# Evaluate NDSolve within NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

So I am attempting to solve a differential equation which includes a differential equation (i am not sure if this why my code is giving problems). I am pretty sure that everything is as its supposed to be.

My code isn't giving any errors, but its literally just spitting back out what I put in, which makes me think its because the interpolating function thats within the NDSolve isn't evaluating correctly. Is there a way around this?

Here is my code:

```
Ro = .007;
Caorta = 1/.48;
k = 110;
ω = 2 π;
x = 1000000;
Rsystemic = 3.1;
Vo = 108;
Cheart = 6.67;

Fao[t_] := ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10) - Paorta[t])/
   Piecewise[{{Ro, 1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t] > 0}},
     x*Ro] /. 
   NDSolve[{Paorta'[t] == 
      1/Caorta ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t])/
          Piecewise[{{Ro, 
             1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10 - Paorta[t] > 0}}, 
           x*Ro] - Paorta[t]/Rsystemic), 
     Paorta[0] == 90}, {Paorta[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];

NDSolve[{Vheart'[
    t] == ((1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 
         10) - (((Vheart[t] - Vo)*(1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 
             10)) + Vheart[t]/Cheart))/
     Piecewise[{{Ro, 
        1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 
          10 - (((Vheart[t] - Vo)*(1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 
                10)) + Vheart[t]/Cheart) > 0}}, x*Ro] - 
    Evaluate[Fao[t]], Vheart[0] == 108}, Vheart[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I know for a fact that the Fao[t] works fine, which is why i am not sure what my issue is.

Thanks for you help, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your `Fao[ ]` doesn't work as posted.

```
Ro = .007;
Caorta = 1/.48;
k = 110;
ω = 2 π;
x = 1000000;
Rsystemic = 3.1;
Vo = 108;
Cheart = 6.67;
m[ω_, t_]      := 1/2*k*(1 + Cos[ω t]) + 10
PaoMwt[ω_, t_] := m[ω, t] - Paorta[t]
pw[fun_]       := Piecewise[{{Ro, fun > 0}}, x*Ro]
VhMwt[ω_, t_]  := m[ω, t] - ((Vheart[t] - Vo)*m[ω, t] + Vheart[t]/Cheart)

sol = First@ NDSolve[{Paorta'[t] ==  1/Caorta (PaoMwt[ω, t]/pw@PaoMwt[ω, t] - 
                      Paorta[t]/Rsystemic), Paorta[0] == 90}, {Paorta[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];

Fao[t_] := PaoMwt[ω, t]/pw@PaoMwt[ω, t] /. sol;

sol1 = NDSolve[{Vheart'[t] ==  VhMwt[ω, t]/pw@VhMwt[ω, t] - Fao[t], 
                Vheart[0] == 108}, Vheart[t], {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[Vheart[t] /. sol1, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why is it necessary to separate the actual function and the solution to the DE which I need to replace when defining Fao? Just for my future reference and to better understand programming in general.

Comment: And what does the command "First@" do? Sorry if these are really stupid questions, I am really trying to better understand the way mathematica works and how I can better use it

Comment: @Dinomite00 C'mon, you can't show that kind of lazyness! Go and look up `First[ ]` in the docs!

Comment: I did do that haha, okay maybe I asked the wrong question. I looked it up the second I saw it and didn't recognize it and I know what it does, I am not sure why it is necessary since there isn't more than one output, or not that I can see at least. When I take it out, it no longer works which is why I am a little confused

Comment: @Dinomite00 http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica